# How do I use the apostrophe-s ('s) properly in these three sentences?

Tags: apostrophe, titles

Which one of these three sentences is correct?

> A. Best Soccer Player Haircuts Ever (This is what I find on Google to be the correct one.)
>
> B. Best Soccer Players Haircuts Ever
>
> C. Best Soccer Player's Haircuts Ever

Why is the third one incorrect? What is the point of using an apostrophe-s ***('s)***? We say "**his haircut**", so, if we use "**soccer player**" instead of "**his**", there must be an apostrophe-s **('s)**. Am I right?

Comment: No. The haircut you offer does not belong to any soccer player. It is similar to one that a player might have.

Comment: Would you help me with more examples? I'm still confused!